# Fetching data from Firebase Database and matching with user input in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if user enters their number, it will check if number exists in database or not, if exists, It will match the password provided by user with the password exists in database and if both are same it will to the item screen.

[image: This Is the database structure.]

Here is my code: In this code it fetches the password two time first time it shows password and second time it shows null.

```
  onPressed: () {
          if(numberController.text=='' || passwordController.text==''){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please Fill all the fields");
            debugPrint("Please Fill all");

          }
          else {
            var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                .reference().child("NewUsers");
            dbRef.orderByKey().equalTo(
                numberController.text).once().then((
                DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                  debugPrint("hello");
              if(snapshot.value !=null){
                debugPrint("world");
              if (snapshot.value.isNotEmpty) {

                var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                    .reference().child("NewUsers").child(numberController.text);
                ref.once()
                    .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                  print(snapshot.value);
                  snapshot.value.forEach((key, values) {
                    print(values["Password"]);
                    if(passwordController.text==values["Password"]){
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/item');
                      debugPrint("CorrectPassword");
                     // Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Correct Password");
                    }else{
                      debugPrint("InCorrectPassword");
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Incorrect Password");
                    }
                  });
                });
              }
              else{

              }
              }
              else{
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please Signup First');
                debugPrint("Please Signup First");
              }
            });
          }
        },
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use firebase_auth package to handle user authentication? Also keeping passwords as plain text on the db is not really a good idea. IMHO

Comment: Hey @GrahamD, thanks for the suggestion I will definitely do that but for so many other conditions I have to fetch many records form database which must be  corresponding to the provided number and for that I have to do the same process with other fields so I ask this as a reference.

Comment: What 'number' are you referring to? I presume this is a number you allocated them. Please explain why they need to enter this number instead of them being recognised as an authenticated user, just to help me understand the use case. :-)

Comment: you are over complicating the process

Comment: @GrahamD, number is the 10 digit numeric child of NewUsers given in the picture.